# What exactly does "AJAX_MODE" => "Y" parameter do?

Tags: ajax, bitrix

In Bitrix docs at http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/user_help/service/form/components_2/form.php and in various articles about AJAX in Bitrix it is very poorly explained what exactly does `"AJAX_MODE"=>"Y"` in a component's configuration do. Can anyone explain what it changes when set to `"Y"`?

Comment: I have no idea, but don't you think it makes the PHP component use an AJAX request for submit, as opposed to a page request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set `AJAX_MODE` as `Y`, the component will try to work without reload page. For example: when you change page, bitrix will try reload `WORK_AREA`.

If you know russian language, you can read it http://www.1c-bitrix.ru/blog/rsv/253.php

Comment: Thanks for the article, I didn't manage to find it myself. However, now I did also find the official documentation piece on AJAX ib Bitrix which is by some reason not on the official website: http://yunaliev.ru/file/bitrix_ajax_api.pdf